# How to suppress logging with Google Analytics 7.3?

Tags: android, logging, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

The latest update to Google Play Services 7.3 makes GA's [`Logger` interface deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/Logger.html), and thus we cannot control the logging level from inside our app anymore.

> This interface is deprecated.
>
> Logger interface is deprecated. Use `adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG` to enable debug logging for Google Analytics.

We used to have different settings per build type, using [`Logger.setLogLevel()`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/advanced#logger) (the guide seems to be outdated): verbose for debug and error for release, so that our tracking information is available only to us during development.

Now with latest update, anyone who can run

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 VERBOSE
```

will be able to see what we are sending to Google Analytics, or anyone can see what everyone else is logging (those who use 7.3).

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation use `adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG` in android studio terminal but make sure you connect one device only then enter `adb logcat -v time -s GAv4` in terminal to start track logger

> Logger
>
> Google Analytics will log to logcat under the GAv4 tag using the
>   Android Log system. By default only ERROR, WARN and INFO levels are
>   enabled. To enable DEBUG level run the following adb command on your
>   device or emulator:
>
> adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG To see only Google Analytics
>   messages from logcat use the following command:
>
> adb logcat -v time -s GAv4

reference 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/advanced#logger

Comment: The question is how to avoid other people set this and see your tracking log.

Answer (score 0):

In the Google Analytics changelog page you can see that GA Version 4.5 is the version which is included in Google Play Services 7.3 (May 1, 2015)

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/changelog

You can change the default Logger to a custom implementation:

```
Custom implementations of Logger can also be used:

// Provide a custom logger.
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).setLogger(new CustomLogger());
```

See: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/advanced

Comment: Well, `GoogleAnalytics.setLogger(Logger)` is also deprecated. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics.html#setLogger(com.google.android.gms.analytics.Logger)